# Replacing damaged ethernet port

Tags: pi-2, ethernet

The ethernet port on my Raspberry Pi 2 is damaged, can it be replaced?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean replace with another solution, yes. You could use a USB-Wired Ethernet adapter. I'm using [TP-Link adapters](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00007IFED) and they work quite well.

If you mean physically repaired, while it's not impossible, the effort will likely cost more than the price of a new RPi 2B or require specialized skills. The RPi additionally needs integrated magnetics, so it's not just a simple RJ-45 jack replacement. See [this article](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/manufacturing-hiccup/) for a description.

Comment: Thanks guys for your suggestions, TP-link adapter should be better than surgery.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you would need to:

1. Know how to desolder, and be able to do it carefully. There are 8
   datapins on the jack, plus 4 pins (2 for each) for the LEDs, plus 2
   tabs on the side. So 14 connections to desolder.
2. Buy a new jack. The ones used on the Rpi are made by EDAC, Inc (at
   least on my RPi2), and [this item on
   DigiKey](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/A63-113-331P4D2/151-1154-ND/3528286)
   is the closest one I can find. With shipping inside the US this will
   set you back ~$11 for one. Note that it has special tabs on the top and the side which seem to be made for holding it in place inside an enclosure - these might lead to an incompatibility with RPi enclosures, but maybe they can be removed ...
3. Solder on the new jack, making all 14 connections correctly.

All in all, this is going to cost you money - (about 1/3rd of the price of a new one) and lots of time (Unless you're a (de)solder wizard, at least an hour of desoldering+soldering+prying the old socket out). As Bobstro correctly mentions, buying a new one might be a faster alternative, or using a USB-Wired Ethernet adapter. I have a UTechSmart lying around [which I bought for $12 on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00F41TWAO).

Comment: I gave this solution a try but unfortunately I couldn't get it to work. It looks like this jack has magnetic coupling installed but perhaps it's somehow incompatible with the rPi. It looks like the best solution is to just bite the bullet and go for a USB adapter.

Answer (score 0):

(I know this question was from ages ago, but I needed to replace a socket on my Pi and found this from Google)

So long as you have the tools to remove the damaged socket without damaging the PCB (e.g. desoldering station), then fitting a replacement is straight forward although a bit time consuming.

Unfortunately the Raspberry Pi Foundation hasn't provided the manufacturer part number of the socket used in the Pi 3B or earlier, so some reverse engineering is needed.

As it happens, I needed to replace the socket on a Pi 3B (not 3B+, which has a 10-pin socket for gigabit Ethernet), which I believe is the same or equivalent to the Pi 2's socket.

From what I could find out by examining the 3B's socket, it is most likely EDAC part A63-112-313P190. Seems it is difficult to get that exact part, but there are places that sell equivalent sockets.

One that I've tested to work on my Pi 3B is Bel Fuse SI-60062-F, which is much easier to get, stocked on Digikey and others.